# NodeJS - get current color of windows cmd

Tags: windows, node.js, colors, cmd, stream

I am writing one application that process data and show output in windows command prompt. During processing phase the application makes few http calls, does some internal processing and shows the result. Hence it takes some time. I want to show the status of results in different colours. Like

Feeding configuration [Current cmd bg and fg]
Calling remote service [Current cmd bg and fg]
   Service-1 (100%) [Red]
   Service-2 (100%) [Red]
Processing service result [Current cmd bg and fg]

bg : Background, fg: Foreground

I am able to achieve that from the following code

```
var Writable = require("stream").Writable,
ws,
Readable = require("stream").Readable,
rs;

rs = new Readable();
ws = new Writable();


rs.push(Buffer([0x1b, 0x5b]));
rs.push("31");
rs.push("m");
rs.push(null);
process.stdout.write("hey\n");
process.stdout.write("hey");
setTimeout(function(){
  rs.pipe(process.stdout);
  setTimeout(function(){
    process.stdout.write("---");
  }, 1000);
}, 2000);
```

This changes the font to red like
[image]

Now I want to get back the old settings (not default) of colors which was there before change of text. (Blue font, gray background).

**How can i get that?** There is an option to get the default color by changing the code to

```
rs.push(Buffer([0x1b, 0x5b]));
rs.push("0");
rs.push("m");
rs.push(null);
```

But changes to default cmd color(white fg black bg my default cmd color)
[image]

But the users default color selection (Right click on cmd icon in top left corner -> default) of cmd can be different from current color selection (Right click on cmd icon in top left corner -> properties).

Ref link [Color change - ANSI escape code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#CSI_codes)

**My question is, how can i get the  colors settings that was in effect before changing the text color to red?**

Thanks.

Comment: Are you aware of [chalk](https://github.com/sindresorhus/chalk)?

Comment: @AleksandrM I was not aware of chalk. But I know ansi-styles which is used by chalk. Given that, once ansi-styles is used to color cmd it changes text back to default color, not the current color selection. I have mentioned it at the last section of my comment. And this is something what I want to avoid.

Comment: I see what you mean now.